# Can't bring two arrays into one to fetch sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Its might sounding like a noob question but I can't find an answer. Currently I have this.

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $gridData[] = array(
                'CompanyName' => $row['CompanyName'],
                'ContactName' => $row['ContactName'],
                'ContactTitle' => $row['ContactTitle'],
            'Address' => $row['Address'],
            'Country' => $row['Country'],
            'Parent' => $row['Parent'],
            'City' => $row['City'],
            'id' => $row['id']
      );
}
```

but assuming I don't want to hardcode this fields there I have another array which is stored in $fields and has the structure of an array inside so field [0] is the fieldname.

so I do

```
 foreach ($fields as $field)
     {
       $gridData[$field[0]] => $row[$field[0]];
     }
```

by some reason it does not work like this. what is the way to do this properly?
How can I bring this together?

Comment: why you don't do it like this `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { $gridData[] = $row;}` ?

Comment: i don't understand your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$gridData[] = array()
```

will add a numerical index to the $gridData array with value of what is in the array.  You are trying to do

```
$gridData[$field[0]] => $row[$field[0]];
```

which is trying to reference a string index.
Try:

```
foreach ($gridData as $rowIndex => $gridRow){
  foreach ($fields as $field)
  {
    $gridData[$rowIndex][$field[0]] => $row[$field[0]];
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you would be ok modifying your field data structure, you could use 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: I don't get it have a $gridData[$i] now

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            $gridData[] = $row;
```

Or this way:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   array_push($gridData, $row);
```

EDIT : If you really want to only get some columns of your table, you have to filter them before in the query:

```
$fields=Array("name", "firstname");
$query="SELECT ".join(",", fields)." FROM table WHERE";
```

Anf if your structure of `$fields` is, as said in a previous comments, an array of array `$fields=Array(Array("name"), Array("firstname"));` you can extract a well formatted array for the previous command with `array_map(create_function('$a', "return $a[0];"), $fields)`

Comment: where is the $fields and the single $field[0] in this?

Comment: As you said, the goal is not to hardcode the fields name. If you only want certain column of your table, you have to do it in your SQL query, not after the query was done. I add an extra edit for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
$e=count($fields);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {


        $gridData[$i]=array( );

        $e=0;
        $fin=count($fields);
        //echo "<h1>".$fin."</h1>";
        while ($e < $fin){
        $gridData[$i]=array_merge($gridData[$i], array( $fields[$e][0] => $row[$fields[$e][0]]));
        $e++;
        }

         $i++;}
```

I am quite not sure why this works